# JavaScript RegExp Multiple Named Capture Groups

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I would like a RegExp to capture the number of pics, vids and writings in a string. That string could contain one, two, all or none of the categories. This is the closest I've got to those results.

Your help will be richly rewarded in a previous life.

```js
const text = "\t\t                          3222 pics\n" +
             "\t\t                          20 vids\n" +
             "\t\t                          1 writing\n";
console.log(text);

const pattern = /(?<pics>(\d+(?= pic)?))(?<vids>(\d+(?= vid)?))(?<writings>(\d+(?= writing)?))/gi;

matches = pattern.exec(text);
console.log(matches);
console.log("pics : " + matches.groups.pics); //expecting 3222
console.log("vids : " + matches.groups.vids); //expecting 20
console.log("writings : " + matches.groups.writings); //expecting 1
```

Comment: Do you really need to execute this process in a single regex? You could simply use three differents regex, which would remove the need for capture groups.

Comment: If it is in any order, you could check for the capture group names `(?<pics>\d+(?= pic))|(?<vids>\d+(?= vid))|(?<writings>\d+(?= writing))` https://regex101.com/r/gxLDh1/1 Note that you should not make the lookahead optional and you can omit the extra capture group by just using the named groups.

Comment: Maybe you are overcomplicating things. Something like [`(\d+) (pic|vid|writing)`](https://regex101.com/r/p4qWDM/4) could suffice, see [this JS demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##nY/LDoIwEEX3/YorG9oQQevGSPgSyoJAgzXlEahAIn57LerGhTFxFjOLuWdy5pKP@VD0qjPb8Wht0TaDgZGzQQJPGGHwtQ6cc3SqGETjISAfux8o32FU5R/gHlOvjGoqh8aEvHR7WcnZ@UZUlAEDdU6LO7@8oyyqlMtqaVDHZDorLUFp7YAnGMpZFnR9mTFskgTNVWuGm/Naz7dahrqtaJ3yDAH8wV/7Ceuo033GYnK39gE).

Comment: @Nicolas: I could, but that would be too easy. ☺️

Comment: @Thefourthbird: That looks great in regex101, doesn't it? However, in the browser I get "undefined" for vids and writings.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Just like 4thBird's code, your's also only returns pic.

Comment: @DataZombies You would have to loop all the matches and check the capture group values. See for example https://jsfiddle.net/ojLb2yds/

Comment: @DataZombies Have you tried [the JS demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##nY/LDoIwEEX3/YorG9oQQevGSPgSyoJAgzXlEahAIn57LerGhTFxFjOLuWdy5pKP@VD0qjPb8Wht0TaDgZGzQQJPGGHwtQ6cc3SqGETjISAfux8o32FU5R/gHlOvjGoqh8aEvHR7WcnZ@UZUlAEDdU6LO7@8oyyqlMtqaVDHZDorLUFp7YAnGMpZFnR9mTFskgTNVWuGm/Naz7dahrqtaJ3yDAH8wV/7Ceuo033GYnK39gE) that I provieded in the comment? Looking for(back)ward to getting the precious reward in previous lifes and hoping it will have some impact on this one. 

Answer (score 2):

You could extract any pair of integer and word that occur at the end of a line, and construct an object from those pairs (as key/value pairs):

```js
const text = "\t\t                          3222 pics\n" +
             "\t\t                          20 vids\n" +
             "\t\t                          1 writing\n";

const regex = / (\d+) (\w+)\n/gi;

const res = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(text.matchAll(regex), ([, val, key]) => [key, +val])
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach here would be to utilize *single-line* mode, and just isolate the numbers from the text.

```
(\d+) pics.+?(\d+) vids.+?(\d+) writing
```

```js
var s = `\t\t                          3222 pics
\t\t                          20 vids
\t\t                          1 writing`
var p = /(\d+) pics.+?(\d+) vids.+?(\d+) writing/gs
var m = p.exec(s)
console.log("pics : " + m[1])
console.log("vids : " + m[2])
console.log("writings : " + m[3])
```

Comment: The question states "That string could contain one, two, all or none of the categories"